# Where is the CSS file called in Wordpress?

Tags: css, wordpress, header

I am trying to find where my Wordpress theme calls the CSS file but should it be in header? I have checked there and cant see any reference to it.

Comment: I need each theme is different of course but I can imagine where else it could be.

Comment: I´m not using WP, but you can try to search using Ctrl+Shift+F over the whole WP folder string `link rel="stylesheet"`. It should be in st. like `header.php`, I expected.

Comment: Thank I will check that. Damn though why are people marking this down? Seems like a legit enough question no?

Answer (score 1):

Any properly coded theme should register/enqueue scripts and stylesheets via the `wp_enqueue_scripts` hook. This should all be in your functions.php file or any other file that is called into the functions.php file

You can just do a search inside your functions.php or functions related files. You should never add scripts or styles directly inside your footer or header

Answer (score 1):

In WordPress You Don't Want To Give css file path .It  has pre define css file path in function.php file.

If you change css file structure then you want to change style file path in function.php file.

and also add your new style.css file with.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php bloginfo('template_url')?>/css/yourcssfilename.css">
```

www.sitename\theme\wp-content\themes\themename\css\yourcssfilename.css